# How can I nest a code chunk within an enumerate environment when using R Markdown?

Tags: r, knitr, markdown, rstudio

When I attempt to do this using this code:

````
---
title: "Title"
author: "Me"
date: "31 October 2014"
output: 
    pdf_document:
        includes:
            in_header: includes.sty
---

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*})]
    \item 
    \begin{enumerate} 
        \item
        ```{r}
            print("test")
        ```


    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
````

includes.sty just contains:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
```

R studio does not recognise the chunk as a valid code block (no syntax highlighting), and when compiling I get the error:

```
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
l.199         #
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Okay, I've added the full file. Adding \documentclass{...} isn't necessary in this instance (as I'm guessing that it is automatically included when the source is compiled).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are basically two things causing errors in your sample code:

1. By default, knitr prefixes R output with `##`, which can't be present in your TeX file. You have to substitute something else for it.
2. Code chunks can't be indented, so you'll have to excuse your OCD self and flush the chunk to the left of your source code.

So this alone makes improves your code:

````
\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    \begin{enumerate} 
        \item
```{r, comment="", results="asis"}
print("test")
```
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
````

Your PDF should look like this:

[image: asis]

Notice how the final product is a monstrous TeX-knitr hybrid. It interpreted the R markdown, but printed everything in LaTeX. Notice how the triple quotes were converted to double quotes + single quote. Removing `results="asis"` just makes things a bit worse, because then the answer also gets those quotes.

[image: markup]

I've found an [awesome answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27334272/1169233) that shows a nice trick to get proper formatting. You just have to rename your environment:

````
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
- \newcommand{\benum}{\begin{enumerate}}
- \newcommand{\eenum}{\end{enumerate}}
---
\benum
  \item 
    \benum
      \item
```{r, results="asis"}
print("test")
```
    \eenum
\eenum
````

Result:

[image: newcommand]

Removing `results="asis"` should give better (i.e., monospaced) formatting for the R output, but instead it just yields the following error on my machine:

> LaTeX Error: \begin{enumerate} on input line 664 ended by \end{document}.

---

### **TL;DR**

1. Renew your commands on the preamble (e.g.: `\newcommand{\benum}{\begin{enumerate}}`)
2. Don't indent your chunk
3. Use `results="asis"`

Comment: This is a brilliant answer, thanks a lot for this. Never would have worked it out myself!

Comment: @JackWoot: thanks! Please remember to vote it up. :)

Comment: Not enough reputation unfortunately, but I selected it as best answer. I'll be back to do so once I do.

Comment: I don't normally respond to these; but, thank you. This worked beautifully for my issue as well. I was trying to put my code in a column environment and ended up using the following based upon the answer above: `\usepackage{multicol} \newcommand{\btwocol}{\begin{multicols}{2}} \newcommand{\etwocol}{\end{multicols}}`

Comment: @AlisonShelton, I'm glad to be of assistance. In order to help the community, please remember to upvote answers you find useful.

Comment: works for me even without the 'asis'.  Remember to put keep_tex: true in your setup and debug the latex directly

Answer (score 1):

R Markdown generates a .tex file when we hit the Knit to PDF option. If the .tex file does not contain any wrong Latex command, it gets converted to PDF, and R Markdown deletes it (and we never see it). We plan to see how the R Code chunk becomes in latex formatting if we put it outside of any list. If we get it, then we can put it inside a list.
Suppose we want to write a code chunk containing only print("Test") inside an ordered list (with proper formatting). Steps:

1. First, we put the chunk outside of any list.

```
print("Test")
```

2. But, how can we see the .tex file. We put any wrong Latex command so that the .tex file does not get converted to PDF and R Markdown cannot delete it. Like we put,
   \item (without \begin{itemize} and \end{itemize}).
3. Open the .tex file in any Text Editor, copy the code chunk along with the output (if any). In my case, the code was like this,

```
\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\KeywordTok{print}\NormalTok{(}\StringTok{"Test"}\NormalTok{)}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}

\begin{verbatim}
\## [1] "Test"
\end{verbatim}
```

4. Now, in the original R Markdown file, paste it after \item.

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\KeywordTok{print}\NormalTok{(}\StringTok{"Test"}\NormalTok{)}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}

\begin{verbatim}
## [1] "Test"
\end{verbatim}
\end{enumerate}
```

5. Delete the wrong Latex command.
6. Hit Knit to PDF.
   In my case, the result is:
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

With verbatim the output it's not perfect but it's a simple solution:

````
\begin{itemize}
\item Solution:
  \begin{verbatim}
  ```{r}
  t.test(dados, alternative="greater") 
  ```
  \end{verbatim}
\end{itemize}
````

Comment: Could you explain how your a swer works? Nevertheless, welcome to TEXSE.